Get direct sound values from the device and not microphone in python
I have created a little sound player in python as an experiment, and I would've find it cool if I could have a sound visualizer in the command line. So I began to search ways, and I found some, but they used the microphone (sounddevice, pyAudio). Isn't there a way to get direct values from the machine (Windows)?
Sorry if there was already an answer, but I didn't find it.
I tried this to try and use it to build my own: https://github.com/aiXander/Realtime_PyAudio_FFT.
But, as soon as I tried it, I saw it was using the microphone (it's using sounddevice or pyAudio).

Getting the overall audio output of the system is pretty difficult, particularly in python. It will likely be much easier if you use the data coming from your sound player that's already in python, and just visualize that. How does your sound player work? If it only plays audio files on your system, you could read the file using the soundfile library, and visualize using that data while it's being played out loud
